# Insert CSV data into django model using executemany

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python, executemany

I have a csv file which have around 900000 rows with 13 columns, everything works fine till 28445 rows but after that it gives error

> ProgrammingError
>
> Exception Value:   not enough arguments for format string

I tried to check whether there is something wrong in the column by printing row, but again nothing seems wrong there.

> ['INDIA', '5', '1ST TIME MOTHER', 'PATNA', 'A2', 'BRAND DRIVERS', '', '', 'Is hard to find', '', '', '1', '0 to 12 months']

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = ''' INSERT INTO johnson_jnjusage (country,no_of_people_house,nursing_cnt,city,sec,bucket,category1,category2, final_category, responders, usageFrequency, base, child_age_group) 
                    VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) '''
        x=[]
        reader = csv.reader(request.FILES['csvData'],delimiter=',')
        i = 0
        for row in reader:
            x.append(tuple(row))
            if i>=5000:
                cursor.executemany(query,tuple(x))
                transaction.commit()
                x=[]
                i=0

            i = i+1

        cursor.close()
        return HttpResponse( docfile.name + "'s data inserted into database successfully")
```

If you guys can help me with this 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have 13 arguments in format string and just 11 in your row. I think the exception message is pretty descriptive.

Comment: DmitryMikhaylov there are 13 values in the row but 4 are empty strings('').

Comment: Or is there a way to do this same task using "bulk_create"?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you have commas in double quotes.

Comment: About `bulk_create`: yes. Just create objects, append them to empty list and then run the `bulk_create`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```
#models.py
class JNJUsage(models.Model):
    ...

# views.py (where ever def upload is)
to_create = []

for i, row in enumerate(reader):
    j = JNJUsage()
    j.country = row['country']
    j.no_of_people_house = row['no_of_people_house']
    j.nursing_cnt = row['nursing_cnt']
    j.city = row['city']
    j.sec = row['sec']
    j.bucket = row['bucket']
    j.category1 = row['category1']
    j.category2 = row['category2']
    j.final_category = row['final_category']
    j.responders = row['responders']
    j.usageFrequency = row['usageFrequency']
    j.base = row['base']
    j.child_age_group = row['child_age_group']

    to_create.append(j)

    # If 900k is too much then you could consider something like this
    if i % 10000 == 0:
        JNJUsage.objects.bulk_create(to_create)
        to_create = []

# Clean up the rest
JNJUsage.objects.bulk_create(to_create)
```

Comment: If i use this solution, here also i get the same error "list is out of index"

Comment: Does your CSV have headers? `reader = list(csv.DictReader(request.FILES['csvData']))`

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use bulk_create. It would look something like this:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        x=[]
        reader = csv.reader(request.FILES['csvData'],delimiter=',')
        i = 0
        for row in reader:
            obj = new MyObject()
            obj.country = row[0]
            obj.city = row[3]
            ...
            x.append(obj)
            if i>=5000:
                MyObject.objects.bulk_create(x)
                x=[]
                i=0

            i = i+1
        return HttpResponse( docfile.name + "'s data inserted into database successfully")
```

You can find more info about `bulk_create` in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create).

Comment: please provide more info. In what line do you get this exception? Maybe you could put traceback into your question.

Comment: It looks like some of the lines in your file are empty. Otherwise why would you have an empty list?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Just checked the size of the row and then escaped that particular row, and also i was getting some characters like "\x00", so used regular expression to remove them.

```
def upload(request):
    start_time = time.time()
    print start_time
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cursor = connection.cursor()    
        x=[]
        docfile = request.FILES['csvData']

        reader = csv.reader(request.FILES['csvData'],delimiter=',')

        to_create = []
        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            if len(row) != 13:
                reader.next()
                continue

            j = JnJUsage()
            j.country =row[0]
            j.no_of_people_house = row[1]
            j.nursing_cnt = row[2]
            j.city = row[3]
            j.sec = row[4]
            j.bucket = row[5]
            j.category1 = row[6]
            j.category2 = row[7]
            j.final_category = re.sub(r'[\x00-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f-\xff]', '', row[8])
            j.responders = row[9]
            j.usageFrequency = row[10]
            j.base = row[11]
            j.child_age_group = row[12]

            to_create.append(j)

            # If 900k is too much then you could consider something like this
            if i % 10000 == 0:
                JnJUsage.objects.bulk_create(to_create)
                to_create = []
        JnJUsage.objects.bulk_create(to_create)

        return HttpResponse( docfile.name + "'s data inserted into database successfully")
```

Thanks Dmitry Mikhaylov and Nathaniel for helping out

Comment: def safe_unicode(obj, *args):
    """ return the unicode representation of obj """
    try:
        return unicode(obj, *args)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        # obj is byte string
        ascii_text = str(obj).encode('string_escape')
        return unicode(ascii_text)

Comment: maybe that function is better than a re?